# Symfony 5 - install FOS js routing Bundle

Tags: javascript, symfony

I try to use fos js routing bundle but my jsfiles or react components can see object Routing.
I followed steps and everything installed correct. But when reload the page it looks like route.js it's not recognize.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

What is wrong?

Please help.

Comment: Have you followed these instructions? https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/installation.html

Comment: Yes, On my project and on completely fresh symphony installation

Comment: Look at the paths. There is 'build' in the path.